# Can VLC Player be embedded in a microcontroller to play videos?

Tags: embedded, arduino, microcontroller, vlc, video-player

I would like to know if there's any controller such as arduino or any other microcontroller that can be programmed to run VLC player embedded in its system. It is probably the best open source player. It would be nice if it could run on a standalone controller, and just plug in your usb to the controller and play videos.

The barebone mini systems are way too expensive around 200 to 400 dollars, and that would be an easy approach, but not cost effective.Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, as most "microcontrollers" lack the memory (or external memory bus) and horsepower needed to do software video decoding.

That generally is a task which falls more to "system on a chip" (SOC) designs, which today are increasingly packaged with hundreds of megabytes of memory stacked on top of a several hundred MHz processor, which may have additional special function hardware acceleration.  Things like the beaglebone family, raspberry pi, and recent set top boxes and smart phones, and of course pocket cameras would be examples.

Note that some of the SOC based boards are not really any more expensive than an Arduino, especially by the time you add I/O shields to the latter.  That's because they are able to leverage modern high density integration and the economies of scale of the consumer-device chip marketplace, to inexpensively put a lot of functionality on one or two chips, which would be far, far more expensive to crudely duplicate using a lot of physically discrete parts in the manner of an Arduino + accessories solution.  And an Arduino is so many orders of magnitude too slow that the first accessory you would have to add to it would be a stand-alone hardware video decoding IC.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chris.
Microcontrollers doesn't have enough memory to decode videos. You need to select some microprocessor with video processing available. On the other side you can get some cheap processors with android capability.They are available for 35-40 $. And gives smooth HDMI output. (Not sure about Plug into USB)

Answer (score 0):

> The barebone mini systems are way too expensive around 200 to 400
>   dollars, and that would be an easy approach, but not cost effective.

Raspberry Pi, about $30 give or take.  Beaglebone black $45, white $89.  pcDuino Lite, $39, pcDuino Dev $59, I could do this all day...

As everyone has already said, you wont port such a heavily operating system dependent program to a microcontroller, for a number of reasons, memory, processor requirements, video, and so on.

if you could say take a stm32f4 or something on the high end of microcontrollers, and create some video player for specific format or formats, the man hours involved would take a fair number of sales to overcome the cost.  Why spend a few months on a project when you can have a raspberry pi or beaglebone shipped in a couple of days?  (or a Roku or Apple TV at a local store).